# How to Read dates in text file using C#

Tags: c#, text-files

I am writing my **logs** in a **text file** at my local location(C:\temp\log.txt) using C#. The text file stored as below

```
 2011-11-17 23:05:17,266 [6] FATAL Application

 2011-11-17 23:05:18,094 [6] FATAL Service

 2011-11-17 23:17:08,862 [6] FATAL Receipts - SaveReceipts
 System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
 at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
 at GID.AAFramework.EntityWrapper.ReceiptFacade.SaveReceipts(IEnumerable`1 records,     String user) in     c:\AdvancedAnalyticsProjects\Surya\Trunk\dotnet_src\GID.AAFramework.EntityWrapper\ReceiptFacade.cs:line 632
```

Now I want to read this file and want to **take the first time log entered date** and **last date**

How can  get the **first time date and last updated date** in this text file?

Now I am reading this text file using following code:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FileLocation);
if (sr != null)
{
  linelist.Add(sr.ReadToEnd());
  LogInfoByDate.Add(FileLocation, "StartDate:" + linelist.First().Substring(0, 10) + "|" + "EndDate:" + linelist.Last().Substring(0, 10));               
}
```

This code I write for taking first time date and last updated date if the **Exception line is single** but its **not working for exception with multiple lines** as I show above. Now this is my problem.Can anyone tell me how to take the first and last date in this text file?

Comment: Should it be not `sr.ReadLine();`

Comment: why don't you use FileInfo's CreationTime and LastWriteTime? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx

Comment: At the moment you aren't processing the file line-by-line, you are just reading the entire thing. It seems to me that you should be reading line by line, checking whether it matches a particular pattern (maybe a regex), and if so, using some DateTime.ParseExact on a substring to get the date...?

Comment: Why don't you write your logs in a easily parseable format or escape newline chars using `Regex.Escape`?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: I used in that way to read the text  file line by line thats why i used. can you please tell me the right way to do this?

Comment: @L.B: Can you please give me a bit more explation about your point of view code?

Comment: @SuryaKavitha If you escaped your log string,for ex, your log wouldn't span multiple lines, so you would able to read line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how to parse this:

```cs
//init datetime list for log entries
List<DateTime> logDates = new List<DateTime>();

//Define regex string
string pattern = @"(?<logDate>(\d){4}-(\d){2}-(\d){2}\s(\d){2}:(\d){2}:(\d){2})";
Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);

//read log content
string logContent = File.ReadAllText("test.log");

//run regex
MatchCollection matches = reg.Matches(logContent);


//iterate over matches
foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    DateTime logTime = DateTime.Parse(m.Groups["logDate"].Value);
    logDates.Add(logTime);
}

//show first and last entry
Console.WriteLine("First: " + logDates.First());
Console.WriteLine("Last: " + logDates.Last());
```

I've removed the comma for the milliseconds just to make it easier to parse.

Regards Florian

Comment: I used your code and Its working now. Thank you so much for your nice code :-)

Comment: @SuryaKavitha: just a sidenote, you can combine cansik's regex with my `DateTime.TryParseExact`. I assume that would be the most robust approach and parses also the millis. But then you need to modify the regex to  get also the millis.

Comment: Can you please explain me what you said?

Answer (score 8):

Here's an approach using LINQ and [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx):

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
var format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff";
var fileDates = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path)
                .Where(l => l.Length >= format.Length
                        && DateTime.TryParseExact(l.Substring(0, format.Length)
                                                , format
                                                , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
                                                , DateTimeStyles.None
                                                , out d)
                )
                .Select(l => d)
                .OrderBy(dt => dt);

if (fileDates.Any())
{
    DateTime firstDate = fileDates.First();  // 2011-11-17 23:05:17,266
    DateTime lastDate  = fileDates.Last();   // 2011-11-17 23:17:08,862
}
```

Comment: I had to vote this one up.  It solved the EXACT problem I faced, right down to getting the earliest and latest dates at the start of each line!